# why this operation is performed in the FFT matlab example?

Tags: matlab, fft

I am new to FFT and I'm using Matlab's FFT example to learn about it. I was able to understand the first half of the code:https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-10
But I got stuck in the following section: 
Compute the two sided spectrum P2.

```
P2 = abs(Y/L);
```

Why is the fft of the corrupted signal (X) divided by the signal's length? and then the absolute value is taken?

I have read wikipedia's explanation of FFT but unfortunately, this operation is not clear to me yet. 
** Also, is `L = 1500` computed from multiplying 1.5 seconds x 1000 Hz? 
Hz = cycle/s then the length of my signal is 1500 cycles?
I would really appreciate it if you could help me clarify my doubts!
Thanks!

Comment: Dividing by the length makes the DFT (what is computed by `fft`) independent of the signal length. It allows you to compare results on signals of different length. `abs` returns the magnitude of the spectrum. It allows you to see at which frequencies there is more signal (plus, you can’t easily plot complex numbers).

Comment: Thank you for your input! Yes, reading further I was able to understand it better! (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1447887). Thanks again!